# Time Required for Initial Blockchain Sync

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, blockchain, synchronization

I am a beginner interested in trading and mining the Monero Cryptocurrency. I am using an Arch based Linux distribution and I have downloaded the `monero-gui` package from the Arch package repository to use for trading Monero. I chose the advanced option when creating a wallet and began syncing the blockchain. The blockchain began syncing very fast initially, but continually slows as it syncs. At the moment it has been syncing for one day and looks like it will take at least a few more days to finish syncing.

My internet speed is solid, but it is currently downloading at about 4 kb/s according to the log. My CPU usage is very low, about 2%, and memory usage is 2 out of 8 gigabytes while the daemon is running.

Is this normal? [Here](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/user-guides/importing_blockchain.html) it says that downloading the raw blockchain from getmonero.org is much slower than syncing it with the dameon, but the dameon is looking to take at least 4 days to download while downloading it from getmonero took only 10 hours.

When researching this issue, it seems like most of the posts complaining about a slow blockchain sync are from at least four years ago, so I am not sure if they are still relevant.

Here is the output from the log in case it is helpful.

```
2021-06-08 15:00:01.172 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-release)
Error: Couldn't connect to daemon: 127.0.0.1:18081
[6/8/21 11:00 AM] 2021-06-08 15:00:40.413 I Monero 'Oxygen Orion' (v0.17.2.0-release)
Height: 1529589, target: 2378781 (64.3014%)
Downloading at 4 kB/s
Next needed pruning seed: 7
4 peers
144.217.248.48:4683 8ca421ea1bf0df7b normal 0 1529589 1 kB/s, 0 blocks / 0 MB queued
92.193.184.167:18080 ca9e6ed33703df47 synchronizing 0 2378781 1 kB/s, 0 blocks / 0 MB queued
51.89.181.106:6508 913a119dcb7c49b5 normal 0 1529589 1 kB/s, 0 blocks / 0 MB queued
147.135.178.157:11296 035c429daa3a78f5 normal 0 1529589 1 kB/s, 0 blocks / 0 MB queued
0 spans, 0 MB
[]
```

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the daemon, it is downloading and simultaneously verifying that it has not been tampered with so that decreases speed.

It also slows down because over time monero block sizes get bigger and bigger due the larger amount of transactions due to monero's popularity growing.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know how long I should expect an initial sync to take?

Comment: @Nick Probably around 1 day to 3 days.

Comment: Using a SSD is a massive boost to sync speed. You can sync from scratch in under half a day with a SSD.

Comment: DavidRoobox, @user36303, thank you. I had a rotating disk drive and the sync crashed after 5 days leaving the database corrupted. I have obtained a speedy SSD and will be trying it today hoping for better results.

Comment: @Nick does it work now?

Comment: @DavidRoobox, thanks for your response earlier. It did work eventually it just took about 5 days and at times seemed unresponsive. Also, it is virtually impossible to sync on a hard drive unless you have a good month to spare.